# Restkit and Core Data rollback

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

In my app I'm using RestKit v0.23.3 and I need to call 4 web service sequentially. I'm doing this without any problem following various tutorial that can be found on the web.

My problem is that **I need to be sure to download all 4 services** or data can be inconsistent.

Now **my question**: can I do a rollback on CoreData if one of the web services fails during the download/mapping operations ? Or is there a mode to disable the "auto save to persistent store" feature that RestKit has and save "manually" only when the last web service has ended ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using NSUndoManager? although in my experience NSUndoManager isn't always reliable.

Comment: Not yet, but I can give it a try and I thank you for the input. Anyway the only reliable way that I can see is passing through NSDictionary instead of mapping object to CoreData entities directly, but I really don't know if this is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really required then I'd be tempted to use a disk based solution - i.e. before you start any potentially destructive / corrupting operation you ensure everything is saved and make a copy of the data store on disk (note that multiple files may need to be saved so best to use API like 
`migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:`). Now, if you have a problem you can tear the Core Data stack down, restore from disk and then recreate the stack. This is safer and more reliable than trying to prevent saving or use an undo manager as the load process is run across multiple threads so you really need the saves to be running.

Comment: This sounds good solution for infrequent changes occurring from infrequent service calls.